# Difference between fgets and fread

Tags: c, post, cgi

I have the following code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int lendata;
    printf("Content-type:text/html\n\n");
    printf("<html><body>");

    lendata = atoi(getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH"));
    char *buf = malloc(lendata+1);
    fread(buf,lendata,1,stdin);

    printf("%s\n<br>",buf); 
    printf("%d",lendata);   

    free(buf);

    printf("</body></html>");
    return 0;
}
```

When I use `fgets`, it truncates the data displayed. But when I use `fread` , it displays all the content. By the way, this is the CGI script for an html file upload using post method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both functions can be found well documented ([fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/), [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)) on the C++ website. Refer to them for the in depth and technical difference.

In short, `fgets` will read until the first new line, maximum bytes to read at once, or `EOF`, which ever is sent first whereas `fread` will read a specific number of *words* (where I define a word as a chunk of bytes, say groups of 4 bytes) and stop when that limit has been reached or 0 bytes have been read (typically means `EOF` or error).

If you wanted to use either function to read until `EOF` then it would look as follows:

```
char buffer[ buff_len ];

// ... zero-fill buffer here.

while ( fgets( buffer, buff_len, stdin ) != EOF ) {
  // ... do something with buffer (will be NULL terminated).
}

while ( fread( buffer, sizeof( buffer[ 0 ] ), sizeof( buffer ) / sizeof( buffer[ 0 ] ), stdin ) != 0 ) {
  // ... do something with buffer (not necessarily NULL terminated).
}
```

Comment: Do you want `char buffer[ buff_len ];` instead?  (no *).  BTW: in `fread( ( void * )buffer`, `( void * )` appears superfluous.

Comment: @chux, that's a typo and I was not sure about the `void` casting so I added it in anyway since I knew regardless it couldn't hurt. Fair point though.

Comment: I recommend the `fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer[0]), sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]), stdin)` style for it adjusts nicely for a re-edited `foo_type buffer[foo_N]`.

Answer (score 4):

`fgets` stops reading on encountering `\n`, while `fread` reads.

Comment: So would I use fgets to read multiple lines which are separated by new lines?

Comment: u can use `fgets` in a loop until `EOF` is reached.