# I cannot read my .txt file in c. I am using codeblocks. I first created an array for the lines before using fgets and trying to print out the lines

Tags: c

I am new to C and i am trying to read a .txt file. I am using a windows 10 machine. I have created the file and i am trying to read it. I will share all my code below.

```
    int main()
{
    char firstline[255]; 
    FILE * fpointer = fopen("klinks.txt", "r");
    fgets(firstline, 255, fpointer); 
    printf("%s", firstline);
    fclose(fpointer); 
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the  message showing on the console terminal. I have no idea why.

```
h┐
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.026 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: Add `fflush(stdout); getchar()`;

Comment: Try to use `read` function instead of fgets, I believe it is better and try to put error messages like `if (fpointer != 0) { perror('fopen') }`, it will help you know where the error comes from

Comment: what line do i add it to please?

Comment: it contains just text.

Comment: Yes, but *what* text? Show the first line of the file. And as an answer says, you did not check that the file opened, or that `fgets` was succcessful.

Comment: Uche: Billionaire (this is the first line of the file)

Comment: `fopen` returns `NULL` on failure. `fgets` also returns `NULL` on failure (if the file was opened, otherwise it is undefined). Also, use `char firstline[255] = "";`

Comment: Side note, this will only read **one** line of your file.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't find the file, and the `fgets` call doesn't do anything, and the output is just the default garbage in `firstline` string.
When you create the file the program works.

Also add a check for null after the `fopen` call.

Comment: I do not know how to add the check. are you also saying that i should create the file? the file is already created. I am just trying to read the file

Comment: @Uche: After the line `FILE * fpointer = fopen("klinks.txt", "r");`, add the line `if ( fpointer == NULL ) { fprintf( stderr, "Error opening file!\n" ); return 1; }` Note that you must insert the newlines into the code yourself, because I can't write newlines in comments.

Comment: guys i have found the mistake. My bad. You pointed me in the right direction. I was trying to read a file that was in another directory. Immediately i copied the file into the same directory that i was trying to read from, the first line showed. Thanks a lot man for telling me that it could not find the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have found the issue. Thnaks a lot again

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the value of file descriptor which is getting returned by fOpen() function just to make sure system call has not failed.

try using fread : fread reads raw data -- it will stop after a specified (or default) number of bytes, independently of any newline that might or might not be present.

You might want to check this : [fgets() and fread() - What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751632/fgets-and-fread-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have found out what the issue is. Thanks a lot again